# C++ output to windows terminal using cout<<term_cc<color, default, attrib> outputs colors and attributes properly on Windows but not on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, parsing, colors

Thought I was done and ready to submit this little project until I got this unexpected curveball.
The objective is to make a parser using a token lexer.
Essentially 
`<underline><red> R <green> G </green> <blue> B </blue> and back to red </red></underline>`
will output as: "RGB and back to red" in their respective colors and attributes.

Everything works fine on windows but when I moved it over to the Linux systems it outputs the color codes with nothing happening.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stack>
#include <map>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector> 
#include "cmd.h"
#include "Lexer.h" // you should make use of the provided Lexer
#include "term_control.h"
#include "error_handling.h"

using namespace std;

map<string, term_colors_t> colorMap;    
map<string, term_attrib_t> attribMap;
string display(const string& expression) 
{
if(validate(expression) == "VALID") {
Lexer lex;
Token tok;

vector<term_colors_t> colorVect;
vector<term_attrib_t> attribVect;

lex.set_input(expression);
while(lex.has_more_token()){
    tok = lex.next_token();
    string sTok = tok.value;
        if(tok.type == TAG && tok.value.at(0) != '/'){
            cout<<term_cc(colorMap[tok.value], DEFAULT_COLOR, attribMap[tok.value]);
            colorVect.push_back(colorMap[tok.value]);
            attribVect.push_back(attribMap[tok.value]);
        }
        if(tok.type == TAG && tok.value.at(0) == '/'){
        colorVect.pop_back();
        cout<<term_cc(colorVect.back(), DEFAULT_COLOR, attribVect.back());
        }
        if(tok.type != TAG){
            cout<<tok.value;
        }
    }
}
else if(validate(expression) != "VALID")    return validate(expression);
return "";
```

}

_

```
    cout<term_cc(Color, DEFAULT_COLOR, Attribute)
```

is the specfic method where the problem is hiding I have been searching around and can't seem to find the proper method.

```
    cout<<term_fg(color)
```

that method properly displays color on the Linux system but I cannot have attributes with that method.

Everything I've been reading pertained only to color not color and attributes they were also using the echo command and hard coded colors for specific terminals. These would require serious changes in all my code and cause it to not work on Windows and only on Linux so I'm trying to avoid this.

Thanks in advance for any advice on this problem everyone I appreciate it hopefully  I'll be able to get this in before 12!

Comment: what is `term_cc` or `term_fg`? Are you using some library? If so, it should be mentioned either in the question or the tags.

Comment: Did you mean `cout<term_cc` or `cout<<term_cc` in the code you presented?

Comment: Added everything sorry about the mixup guys.
And cout<<term_cc @MichaelPetch

Comment: Does your lexer read from a file and if it does does it properly account for the fact that on Windows newlines are CRLF and on Linux it is generally LF?

Comment: It takes the input from console so input would be
display <red> this is red </red>
The lexer was created by the teacher on linux and we are not aloud to touch it so I would assume so.
When it gets a token <red> it knows it's a "tag" and parses out the arrows, returning a string "red". @MichaelPetch

Comment: I had to do some research and interestingly I found some code written in Java that is eerily similar to yours. Seems like the term_fg and term_cc are authored by a professor somewhere. I guess they use ANSI Escape sequences (VT100) on Windows to output color and attributes. Problem on Linux is that you can have a variety of terminal types. There is something called the `termcap` library. It allows one to query the escape sequence commands to do certain things (Like color or attributes like blinking etc). So instead of hardcoding you ask the library what is used to produce certain results.

Comment: Different Terminal types often use different sequences (or may ignore attributes if they so choose) and my guess is that whatever you are using under Linux as a terminal doesn't understand or ignores the attributes. On your Linux box if you open your terminal and type `echo $term` what does it return?

Comment: My question is are you able to modify the methods `term_cc`, `term_fg` etc?

Comment: I should also correct myself Windows uses ANSI.SYS (not VT100).

Comment: I finally tracked down a copy of the files used in these assignments on a cached page on Google. It appears that term_cc, term_fg etc are hard coded assuming a specific terminal type (VT100/Windows ANSI). I can tell by the hard coded \033 escape sequences.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Care to share the exact codes? VT100 will work on Linux, if you have `$TERM` set properly

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I should be clearer. VT100 will work on the Linux console. It will also work with most Linux terminal emulators. It may or may not work with a non-Linux emulator, but I think it works with Putty too.

Comment: As long as $TERM is set properly and the remote end is actually emulating that same type (Earlier I asked for his output for `echo $TERM` so we could learn what type he is using). As for the code download [master.zip](https://github.com/seanfrischmann/250_assignment8/archive/master.zip) . Look in the file term_control.cpp and you'll see the codes they are using.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Yeah, those are standard codes. And according to the OP, `cout<<term_fg(color)` works fine on Linux, so the codes work.

Comment: Yes, however the terminal emulator may not honor all the attributes. It can choose to ignore them as well. I noticed xterm doesn't seem to honor underline and over strike. If I use putty it has a setting to turn blinking on/off.I really think this comes down to what the emulator is accepting and ignoring.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: what code do you claim is overstrike? Both `xterm` and `konsole` respect blink and underline, but the linux console emulates underline with a different colour. I have neither `putty` nor the Windows machine it would run on. If you do, you could try `printf '\e[\0;31;49mRed!\e[0m\n'` and we'd know how putty reacts to NULs in the middle of a console attribute sequence.

Comment: Using Putty from a Win8.1 box that printf prints out Red! in the color red. If I use a value of 1,2,4,5,7,8 (with blinking enabled in Putty's terminal options) all work as expected except invisible which rendered as regular red text. Using Cygwin's terminal all rendered except for blink which rendered as red on a whitish/grey background color but invisible worked. MinGW/Msys terminal didn't honor blink and underline but rest seemed okay

Comment: @MichaelPetch: well, maybe it's not the NUL which is causing problems. There isn't enough code available to know for sure what's going on, but what code there is has enough problems that bugginess seems as likely an explanation as anything. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me where `colorMap` and `attribMap` are initialized and to what values, and I'm just going on instinct here, but it seems likely that the keys for `colorMap` are colours and the keys for `attribMap` are attributes. In that case `underline` is not a key in `colorMap` and `red` is not a key in `attribMap`.

In your program, you do the following:

```
if(tok.type == TAG && tok.value.at(0) != '/'){
        cout<<term_cc(colorMap[tok.value], DEFAULT_COLOR, attribMap[tok.value]);
```

which assumes that every `TAG` is present in both `colorMap` and `attribMap`. But if the tag is a colour like `"red"`, it is (probably) only in `colorMap` and if it is an attribute like `"underline"`, it is (probably) only in `attribMap`.

Now, what happens when you execute `colorMap["underline"]`? Here, the convenience of C++'s standard library can be a bit of a disadvantage because it silently hides an error. The answer is that a mapping from `"underline"` to the default value of a `term_colors_t` is added to the map so that the lookup will always return something. `term_colors_t` is an enum, so its default value is `0` (**not** `'0'`).

Now, `term_cc` -- if it is the same `term_cc` that @MikePetch dug up -- does not check its arguments for validity; it just assumes that they are valid ANSI digits (`'0'` through `'9'`, or in other words a number between 48 and 57, inclusive.) Since it doesn't check them, it just outputs includes them as they are in its output, and since you're (probably) calling `term_cc` with an attributes argument of 0 -- that is, a `NUL` character -- it outputs the `NUL` as part of the supposed console code.

I checked `xterm`, `konsole` and the Linux console, and all of them ignore the `NUL` character. (I believe that is the expected behaviour; DEC terminals like the VT-100 ignored `NUL`s, although in some circumstances you needed to insert them because the terminal would also ignore any character if the previous control took too long.) I don't know what terminal emulator you are using, and it is quite possible that it has different behaviour, such as terminating the control code sequence. `term_cc` outputs the attribute first, even though it is the third argument, so it could well be that a `NUL` attribute would cause the terminal emulator to simply print something like `;31;49m` instead of setting the foreground colour to red.

Some other bugs:

- You never pop `attribVect`; only `colorVect`. So I don't see how the attributes will be properly restored.
- You don't initialize `colorVect` to a `DEFAULT_COLOR`. So after the first tag is popped, you'll pop the (only) element off of `colorVect`, leaving it empty, and then call `colorVect.back()`, which is undefined if `colorVect` is empty.

Those were just the things I notice on a quick skim through the code. There might be other problems.

Comment: I can't see this actually working *properly* even on Windows. It may run but I doubt you are getting the results one expects.